# What difference between

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-timestamp

I have first query

```
select count(*)
from `order`
where marketer_id = 75 and
      HandleStatus != -1 and
      (Created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31')
```

and result is **1050**

i also have second query :

```
select count(*)
from `order`
where marketer_id = 75 and
      HandleStatus != -1 and
      (Month(Created_at) =5 and Year(Created_at) = 2017)
```

and result is **1111**

I think 2 query have same meaning but it return 2 different result.
Info about column "Created_at": COLUMN_NAME Created_at,  COLUMN_TYPE timestamp,  IS_NULLABLE NO,  COLUMN_KEY ,  COLUMN_DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Please help what difference between 2 query?

Comment: Run this query `select count(*)
from order
where marketer_id = 75 and
      HandleStatus != -1 and (Month(Created_at) =5 and Year(Created_at) = 2017) and
     NOT (Created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31')` and see which rows are returned. 

My guess is that there are rows with times (not just the date) in the timestamp.

Comment: between avoid first and last dates

Comment: Learn something new every day here [**demo**](http://rextester.com/DORB47261).  The first query uses May 31st at midnight, excluding the majority of that day.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Here is a variation of your demo: http://rextester.com/DORB47261

Answer (score 7):

If you consider the time within a day, the first query only returns results before 2017-05-31 00:00:00.
If you have any results after 2017-05-31 00:00:00 and before 2017-05-31 23:59:59 (maybe down to milliseconds too), they only show up in the second query.

Answer (score 2):

The first query is not looking at 31st May, it looks only until 30 May. The absence of a time component means the time is taken as midnight, or the start of the 31st.

Answer (score 1):

Between does take only up to '2017-05-30 23:59:59' and after 2017-05-01 00:00:00. It should not consider 31th full day.

If you want first query return same data as second query you can use like this

```
select count(*)
from `order`
where marketer_id = 75 and
      HandleStatus != -1 and
      (Created_at >= '2017-05-01' AND Created_at < '2017-06-01')
```